# Is there a prostate orgasm?

Tags: brain, sexuality, prostate

Is there any scientific evidence that orgasm can be achieved by stimulating the prostate?

The 2023 article "Atlas of the Experience of Receptive Anal Sex in People with a Prostate" states:

> While many debates exist regarding the existence and relationship of
> the “g spot” for men (most often associated with the prostate), there
> is no conclusive empirical evidence to suggest that the prostate is
> indeed responsible for these heightened sensations.

In the 2017 review "Prostate-induced orgasms: A concise review illustrated with a highly relevant case study" wrote (added to the question, but this review was already in the answer):

> Because there have been no published laboratory-conducted
> investigations of the orgasms induced by prostate stimulation alone,
> information about them has to be gathered from the various websites
> dedicated to such orgasms. While unsatisfactory in that the vast
> number are obviously anecdotal they represent the only available
> source

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ca.23006

A related topic is covered in another source:

Sexual Behavior
Problems and Management

Nathaniel McConaghy

> In homosexual relations, most men do not reach orgasm in receptive
> anal intercourse, and a number report not reaching orgasm by any
> method in many of their sexual relationships, which they nevertheless
> enjoy.

https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Sexual_Behavior/eVD0BwAAQBAJ?hl=ru&gbpv=1&dq=In+homosexual+relations,+most+men+do+not+reach+orgasm+in+receptive+anal+intercourse,+and+a+number+report+not+reaching+orgasm+by+any+method+in&pg=PA186&printsec=frontcover

Are there scientific studies with contrary conclusions?

Comment: Where did you look? Did Masters & Johnson ever study the question? We require more than just "I didn't find any evidence."

Comment: Where and how exactly did they prove it?
The question should be read more carefully.

Comment: As far as I know, prostate massage stopped being a mainstream treatment back in the 1960s because it can be harmful

Comment: I didn't say anybody proved anything. I'm asking what research you did and where. This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, and that means more than just saying you can't find any information. So what I asked is where did you look? Masters and Johnson would be my first destination for a question like this.

Comment: I looked at everything that was available to me from Internet sources.  
An example of the opposite:

" It is also typical for a man to not reach orgasm as a receptive partner solely from anal sex."

https://web.archive.org/web/20210310000723/https://books.google.com/books?id=DWN2-QpbvY8C&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Could you add that detail to the body of the question as [comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work): "important information from the original author should be edited into the question".

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: I found a source with similar information and added it to the main part of the question.

Comment: What you added has nothing to do with prostate massage.

Comment: There is a direct relationship between these activities.
If there were more research available specifically on the topic, I would add.
That's why I asked my question here.

Comment: You make that declaration and once again without supporting evidence. It's time to close your question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [*Prostate-induced orgasms: A concise review illustrated with a highly relevant case study*](https://doi.org/10.1002/ca.23006), it appears there is no scientific evidence supporting or refuting the existence of prostate-induced orgasm, or at least there wasn't in 2017.

> Because there have been no published laboratory-conducted
> investigations of the orgasms induced by prostate stimulation alone,
> information about them has to be gathered from the various websites
> dedicated to such orgasms. While unsatisfactory in that the vast
> number are obviously anecdotal they represent the only available
> source.

However, the anecdotal evidence seems compelling:

> Unlike the sparsity of academic literature on prostate-induced orgasms
> there appears to be an enormous number of internet sites involving
> such activity.

My own searches using similar but not identical search terms confirms there are a large number of people out there who claim to be able to induce orgasm with prostate  stimulation. The paper I cited includes a detailed case history of one such man.  Frankly, I see no reason not to believe them, or at least the ones who aren't selling something.

And a paper does exist [*Do men have a G-spot* JF Perry - Aust Forum, 1988] that claims men have an area functionally similar to the G-spot in women, and it is located where the prostate is located. Unfortunately, even though the paper is widely cited I can't find a copy, not even the abstract.

> Perry (1988) suggested that this area of the rectal wall was similar
> to the so-called ‘G-spot’ of the female in that it activated orgasm
> when stimulated so it has been called ‘the male G-spot’, it is
> anatomically incorrect but a widely used description.

So the answer to your question appears to be there is little, if any, scientific evidence supporting the notion of prostate-induced orgasms.

Comment: Importantly, in that paper you reference they mention the possibility of direct nerve stimulation; in other words, it's not really the prostate but a nerve running in the vicinity. The distinction isn't necessarily important, but it would support a mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I relied on this article as well.

But I wondered if the situation had changed since 2017.

Comment: But I see reasons not to trust them. At least when this type of orgasm is unprovenly issued as characteristic of most men. Moreover, it can be harmful and dangerous. Healthcare providers do not recommend prostate massage as a treatment. Massage can be even more dangerous when performed by a non-professional for the sake of pleasure.

Comment: Wait, you knew about this article and yet refused to add it to your question when I asked you for prior research?  What you did add doesn't address the issue. If you read this article you know that achieving orgasm through prostate massage takes quite a bit of time, more time than anal intercourse typically involves. You seem to be more on a mission to prove that thousands of people are lying for no particular reason than actually learning the truth.

Comment: Suppose some of those who make such claims are not lying. From the very beginning, I indicated that I do not deny this 100%.
The source I provided is about men having anal sex in homosexual relationships. I think they are well aware of how long it takes to achieve orgasm, and what needs to be done for this. And these claims are already beginning to irritate.

Comment: No one has accused you of anything. Anal sex and prostate massage are two very different things and many heterosexuals practice prostate massage for the specific purpose of achieving orgasm. Your question is about prostate massage, not anal sex, so the article you included isn't relevant to your question. Therefore, your question still lacks prior research.

Comment: There is a direct relationship between these activities.

Comment: @ggkhj You seem to be quite convinced of that but you have no evidence to support it. Your declaration that it's harmful is also unsupported. This is a science site, not an opinion site. Claims of fact made here are expected to be based on supporting evidence.

Comment: Even that quote you provided in your answer says:

"While unsatisfactory in that the vast number are obviously anecdotal they represent the only available source"

This is what I am writing about. You need to read more carefully before suspecting people of bias.